# How do I change MUI's select background color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am struggling with changing MUI's Select background color. I've tried multiple solutions. I've tried changing it from `<Select/>` className property and it didn't work. Neither did setting it from Menu Prop's. I believe my theme might be causing this problem.

##### My select component

```
            <Select
              variant="standard"
              id={id}
              native={true}
              className={classes.select}
              MenuProps={{
                sx: {
                  maxHeight: 200,
                },
                classes: {
                  paper: classes.paper,
                },
              }}
              inputProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classes.root,
                },
              }}
              sx={{
                border: errors.installments
                  ? "1px solid rgba(255, 0,0,0.5)"
                  : "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
                borderRadius: 1,
              }}
              disabled={installments ?  false : true}
              {...field}
            ></Select>
```

##### The styling sheet

```
export default makeStyles({
  form: {
    minWidth: 280,
    maxWidth: "45%",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)",
    borderRadius: 1,
  },
  select: {
    padding: 10,
    "&:before": {
      borderColor: "white",
      borderRadius: 5,
      content: "''",
    },
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)",
      borderRadius: 5,
    },
    "&:not(.Mui-disabled):hover::before": {
      borderColor: "white",
      borderRadius: 5,
    },
    '&:focus':{
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
  },
  root: {
    color: "white",
    borderRadius: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    overflowY: "auto",
    overflowX: "hidden",
    // So we see the popover when it's empty.
    // It's most likely on issue on userland.
    maxHeight: 200,
  },
});
```

##### The palette defined on the theme

```
  palette: {
    mode: "light",
    primary: {
      main: "#0f9688",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#D96098",
    },
    info: {
      main: "#007668",
    },
    background: {
      paper: "#0f9688",
      default: "ffffff",
    },
  },
```

[MuiSelect with green background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9WfB.png)

Answer (score 7):

You can modify the underlying `<MenuList>` styles by doing:

```
<Select
    inputProps={{
        MenuProps: {
            MenuListProps: {
                sx: {
                    backgroundColor: 'red'
                }
            }
        }
    }}
>
```

Answer (score 3):

**@Emre Tapcı** has good answer. He was so close. But for dark theme there are visible white corners.

I have similar issue, but background is changeable based on selected theme.

My solution is:

```
<Select
  inputProps={{
    MenuProps: {
      PaperProps: {
        sx: {
           backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }}
>
...
</Select>
```

And in case you need it for different themes, better to use variable color:

```
backgroundColor: 'var(--my-background-color)',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sx prop to change the color of the Select Component.

```
<Select
      sx={{ backgroundColor:'red' }}
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={age}
      label="Age"
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select>
  componentsProps={{
    listbox: {
      sx: {backgroundColor: '#000'}
    }
  }}
</Select>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck